# What to do? - An edit was suggested to your post xxx please review it

Tags: support

Sorry, I have no clue how to do what you're suggesting.  I didn't realize that when someone edited a question the questioner did anything.  Help please

Comment: Ha! I have a big smile on my face as that message had me scratching my head for a long time. I finally realized that when I'd visit the site (and my question, etc.) that the edit would already have been reviewed and approved by others, as Justin explained below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you click the "please review it" link differs depending on the reputation of the editor. If the editor has high enough reputation the edit is already made, you can look at it to see what it was. If need be you can make another edit to make additional changes.

If the editor is lower in reputation then you will be given a screen to see the proposed edit. If you agree with the edit you can approve it and the edit will be made.

Answer (score 1):

From [Review](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/review/)

> You need at least 500 reputation to review Suggested Edits.

Once you hit 500 reputation in the private beta, or 1000 reputation in the public beta, you'll be able to approve suggested edits in the review queue, or by clicking the edit link on the post.

In other words, you can vote to approve *any* suggested edit on questions and answers, even on posts that aren't your own. Editing is a big part of making Stack Exchange Q&A great, and it's been known to get 0 voted questions and answers many more upvotes than they would otherwise and help waay more people find answers to their questions.

If a suggested edit is pending on a post, the edit link will appear like this if no one has yet voted:

> edit(0)

Click the link to view the suggested edit.